# android Service to detect that home screen is on

Tags: java, android

Can I write an service in android which detects that we are on home screen and Toast a message. I want to detect that control is currently on home screen.

Let me know if possible.

Thanks,
Pravin

Comment: Seems like a battery drainer to me. Just saying...

Answer (score 2):

In general this will be difficult: see http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6393 for an explanation of why there isn't an Intent to do this.

Staring at the debug log output on any one of my devices there really is no global indicator, so not sure you'll have a lot of luck there.